# React global declare variables getting Flow type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

```js
type Props = {
  checkedItems:any
};
class MyApp extends Component<Props> {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkedItems = [];
  }
 }
```

Here I am using the Flow for the type checking into the react class components.
when I am running this file using **npm run flow** then I am getting the error like
Cannot assign array literal to `this.checkedItems` because property `checkedItems` is missing in`MyApp` [1].
could someone tell me what should I do for this to solve flow error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your code, you have defined type for your prop, but checkedItems is not in props.
You need to define type for class variable `checkedItems`

```
interface IMyAppProps {
    prop1: boolean
    prop2: string
}
interface IMyAppState {
    state1: number
    state2: string
}

class MyApp extends Component<IMyAppProps,IMyAppState> {
    checkedItems: any //defined your class variable here with any type
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.checkedItems = []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the runner is correct, there's no `checkedItems` property defined on the class. By passing `Props` as a type to the `Component` class, you just define the `props` type, you need to define `checkedItems` on the class yourself.

```
class MyApp extends Component<{}> {
checkedItems: any;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkedItems = [];
  }
 }
```